# Convert to Edi files of type RSP and FUL

Tags: c#, edi

Hi I'm looking for a way to genarate edi files of the types rsp, inv and ful now I'm looking at ediFabric and was wondering if this tool has the capabilities for it, i already noticed it can make invoice files but i need the other ones to.

with kind regards

Tobi

Comment: Have you looked at the documentation for ediFabric?

Answer (score 0):

What is the code for the ful file?  ediFabric has a bunch of formats that you can use, but they are for purchase:

```
HIPPA: http://edifabric.com/hipaa/
X12: http://edifabric.com/x12/
EDIFACT: http://edifabric.com/edifact/
```

What is the source of the data?  If it's from a database, or some other data store, you'll probably have to 'new up' one of the EDI pocos (that you would buy) and manually map your data to the fields in the poco.